Authorization Errors After Restoring DB2 Database to V9.7 or Higher
Here’s a message you can use to post on Stack Overflow:

Title: Authorization Errors After Restoring DB2 Database to V9.7 or Higher
Body:
Hi everyone,
I’m experiencing authorization errors after restoring a DB2 database to version 9.7 or higher. Despite being a SYSADM, I encounter errors such as SQL0551N, SQL0552N, and SQL3020N.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I set the DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES registry variable to ON before performing the restore:
db2stop
db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON
db2start


I verified that the variable was set correctly:
db2set -all | grep -i db2_restore_grant


After the restore, I tried to grant DBADM authority to the user db2inst1:
GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE TO USER db2inst1

However, I encountered the following error:
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0552N  "DB2INST1" does not have the privilege to perform operation "GRANT".
SQLSTATE=42502


I checked the users with DBADM and SECADM privileges:
SELECT GRANTEE FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH WHERE DBADMAUTH = 'Y';

SELECT GRANTEE FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH WHERE SECURITYADMAUTH = 'Y';

Users with DBADM authority: DB2, MARWEN, AYMEN.
Users with SECADM authority: DB2, ANYFRAME.


Even though I am using a SECADM user (DB2 or ANYFRAME), I still encounter issues with granting DBADM authority.
Any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Did the name of the instance-owner change between the (original) source-database, and the (new) restored database? Usually easier to do the restore into a Db2-instance that has the same instance-owner name as the source, otherwise you have to transfer ownership...  This is not programming but instead it is an admin question better suited to dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2

Which authorization ID did you use running DB2 RESTORE DATABASE command? According to your SELECT GRANTEE FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH WHERE SECURITYADMAUTH = 'Y' command it should be either DB2 or ANYFRAME (if you haven't revoked SECADM from it afterwards). Right?
